# Does Symfony2 load all translations in memory?

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

Symfony2 stores translations in cache (`app/cache/{dev|prod}/translations/catalogue.fr.php` for instance) whatever provider is used.

This file in cache just defines an array where the keys are for instance in English, and the values in an other language.

Does that mean that this array will grow indefinitely with time as the number of translated strings grows?
If I have translated 10.000 strings, does that mean each request will load this 10.000 array in memory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how PHP works. Symfony will simply look for the segment key inside that "cached" array, which of course has to be loaded in memory.

More in detail, [here](https://github.com/symfony/Translation/blob/master/Loader/ArrayLoader.php) is the ArrayLoader class, which is responsible for loading translation segments from an array.